# compare two arrays and remove not matched objects

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to compare two arrays of objects and removing not matched objects from first array.

> All i need to compare two arrays (array1 and array2) of objects and
>   remove NOT MATCHED objects from the array 1.

This is what i have done till now but it remove all items.

```
for (var i = 0, len = array1.length; i < len; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, len2 = array2.length; j < len2; j++) {
        if (array1[i].Id != array2[j].Student.Id) {
            array1.splice(j, 1);
            len= array1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can add the matched items to a new array, like that newarray only contains matched elements

Comment: Do you want to remove non-matched objects? The code seems to remove matched objects. Another thing is, whether it shout not loop from top index to zero index in array1 and remove elements from the end of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looping over `array1` with `i = 0, len = array1.length; i < len; i++`, but *within* the loop you remove an entry from `array1` what do you think happens on the next loop?

You also appear to be removing things that *are* found, but your question sayd you want to remove ones that *aren't*. In the below, in light of your comment, I'm removing things that *aren't* found.

In that case, use a `while` loop. I'd also use `Array#some` (ES5+) or `Array#find` (ES2015+) rather than doing an inner loop:

```
var i = 0;
var entry1;
while (i < array1.length) {
    entry1 = array1[i];
    if (array2.some(function(entry2) { return entry1.Id === entry2.Student.Id; })) {
        // Found, progress to next
        ++i;
    } else {
        // Not found, remove
        array1.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Or if it's okay to create a new array, use `filter`:

```
array1 = array1.filter(function(entry1) {
    return array2.some(function(entry2) { return entry1.Id === entry2.Student.Id; }));
});
```

Comment: Hopefully you mean by array2.some(function(entry2) is array2[i].Student(function(entry2). Correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: @immirza: Review the documentation for `Array#some`: [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.some) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). Basically, it calls the function for each entry in the array, passing in that entry. If you return a truthy value from it, it stops, and that's the return value of `some`. If you don't, and it reaches the end, it returns `false`. So in this case it's basically saying "If any entry matches".

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder thanks it works for duplicate removal. But as i re-updated in my question i want to remove NOT MATCHED items from array1. Can you please modify your answer please?

Comment: @immirza: You just reverse the condition. I've done it in the above.

Answer (score 2):

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var array2 = [3,4];
var array3 = array1.filter(i => array2.indexOf(i) !== -1);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pLrr3or5/1/

Comment: `filter` isn't necessarily a bad idea, but the OP's code is working with objects, `indexOf` won't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4];
var array2 = [2,4,6,8];
var array3 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
        if (array1[i] === array2[j]) {
            array3.push(array1[i]);           
        }
    }
}

console.log(array3);
> [ 2, 4 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Employees= [{name:"Ram",htno:1245},{name:"mohan",htno:1246},
{name:"madhu",htno:1247},{name:"ranga",htno:1248}]

var seletedEmployees= [{name:"mohan"},{name:"ranga"}];

var nonmatched = Employees.filter(function(val,index) { 
  return seletedEmployees.map(function(e) { return e.name; }).indexOf(val.name) == -1;
});

console.log(nonmatched);
```

Answer (score 0):

**2021**

```
  const a1 = {a:1,b:2,c:3}
  const a2 = {a:1,b:2,c:4,d:6}
  const r = {}
  
  for(const k2 in a2){
    for(const k1 in a1){
      if(k1 === k2){
        r[k1] = a2[k1]
      }
    }
  } 

  console.log(r) // {a: 1, b: 2, c: 4}
```

These for loops run fast and clean in my opinion.
Seems like the cleanest way to handle an object array.